# Simple permutations for all $k$

Tags: permutations

a)How many are the simple permutations of the numbers $ 1,2, ..., n $ in which the k-th element is less than $ k + 4 $, for every $ k $?

b)How many are the simple permutations of the numbers $ 1,2, ..., n $ where the kth element is greater than $ k-3 $, for every $ k $?

Could someone give me a hint? I really didn't understand the statement

Comment: What don't you understand about the statement?  Suppose $n=10$.  Can you give an example of a permutation that passes the given test?  One that does not?

Comment: @lulu how many are the simple permutations. I don't understand what he wants

Comment: Well, you could ask for clarification from whomever set the problem.  There is something called a [Simple Permutation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X05003377)...but of course the writer here might intend something else (perhaps just an ordinary permutation). You should know if something like that might be the intent of the question.

Comment: Just to stress:  I would not say that that definition of a "simple permutation" is at all common or familiar.  I had to look it up to confirm the definition, for instance.  Again, it ought to be clear from the context behind the problem whether such a notion is likely to have been intended.  If not, and if there is no other context, I'd guess they just meant "permutation".

Comment: @lulu Thanks again! I didn't understand that

Comment: As another point:  I have no idea how to solve the problem if this technical notion of "simple" is intended.  I think even the enumeration of the simple permutations is difficult (see [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304213.pdf) for instance).  If you are encountering this problem in a first course on combinatorics, I'd strongly suspect that the author just intends "permutation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1$ must be mapped to $1,2,3$ or $4$. So there are $4$ possibilities.

$2$ must map to $1,2,3,4$ or $5$, less the element that $1$ was mapped to. So there are ? possibilities.

etc...

There will only be $4$ elements for $n-3$ to map to.

There will only be $3$ elements for $n-2$ to map to.

There will only be $2$ elements for $n-1$ to map to.

There will only be $1$ elements for $n$ to map to.

> $6 \times 4^{n-3}$.

Comment: Would simple permutations be the same as combinations?

Comment: For a combination the order of the elements does not matter ... so the constraint would not make sense ?

Comment: Right!! I understand now! Thanks for the tip